# How to pass document object to next view, meteor ionic

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, navigation

How do I pass the currently queried document object onto the next view, without having to query mongo again. I realize I can pass the Id and some arbitrary variables, but how do I pass the entire object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe in your "waitOn function" of your route to the data like:

```
this.route('dashboard', {
    path: '/dashboard',
    layoutTemplate:'mainLayout',
    waitOn:function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('collection1');
        Meteor.subscribe('collection2');
        return Meteor.subscribe('collection3',Meteor.userId());
    },
    data:{
        'collection3':function(){
            return collection3.find();
        }
    },
```

In your publications.js you control what is generally passed to the client.